# Blur event after datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to read the value after a date is picked to check if the date it correct and not in the past.

I work with the datepicker jquery script to select the data and thats working. But the blur focusout isn't working as i want it. I'm i doing something wrong?

```
        $('#verloftot').datepick({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy' }).on('blur focusout',function () {

            alert($('#verloftot').val());

        });
```

Answer (score 3):

Just do an [on change](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for the textbox.

```
var dateTextbox = $('#date');
dateTextbox.datepicker();

dateTextbox.on("change", function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lord_Zero/CD5hw/)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct You using [jquery datepicker](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/) if it's so it have a option [onSelect](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect), it should solve your problem

**onSelect** type: Function( String dateText, Object inst )

Default: null
Called when the datepicker is selected. The function receives the selected date as text and the datepicker instance as parameters. this refers to the associated input field.

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker(
{ 
  onSelect: function(e){
     //Your code here
} });
```

fiddle [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/baximilian/Leq64/2/)

Answer (score 0):

For the extension are you using for your date picker, there are a few options you can use instead of the `onblur`

All of the examples below were copied from the site mentioned in the comments. You should take the time to review the API for the picker to see if there are other options that will help you get the desired behavior.

### [Min/Max](http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html#minmax)

You can specify a min date (comment on site is wrong, the code below restricts to range of Jan 26, 2012 to Jan 26, 2014

```
$('#minmaxPicker').datepick({ 
    minDate: new Date(2012, 1 - 1, 26), 
    maxDate: new Date(2014, 1 - 1, 26), showTrigger: '#calImg'});
```

### [Events](http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html#events)

There are two events that could be useful to you.

**onSelect** allows you to execute a function when a new date is selected

```
$('#onSelectPicker').datepick({ 
    onSelect: function(dates) { alert('The chosen date(s): ' + dates); }, 
    showTrigger: '#calImg'});
```

**onClose** allows you to execute a function when the picker is closed (even if a date is not selected)

```
$('#onClosePicker').datepick({ 
    onClose: function(dates) { alert('Closed with or without date(s): ' + dates); }, 
    showTrigger: '#calImg'});
```

Comment: Updated answer to reference this specific datepick control